# Highstock and Highmaps together causing issue

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

I am using Highmaps in my recent project which already uses Highstock. When both are loaded it throws

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function at line 18 in highstock.js.`

Have anyone tried using both the api together? Help highly appreciated.

[here is the jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/de59en10/1/)

Answer (score 4):

According to this github [issue](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2826).

> You should also have a Highcharts error message saying that Highcharts
>   is already defined. The correct way to combine Highstock and Highmaps
>   is to first load highstock.js (which includes the full Highcharts),
>   then load modules/map.js which is Highmaps as a Highcharts plugin.

Comment: And url to the [docs](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/getting-started) - eplaining how to use Highcharts&Highmaps together. And working [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/de59en10/4/). Note - example is using github version because of bug in maps.js module previously.